# How to close several folders in window 7 using Python

Tags: python-2.7, subdirectory

I seeking a way to close 20 open sub directories in window 7 using this python code. i want to close only those sub directories and not other open directories:

```
import os,sys,re

day = '2.1'
rootdir = r'G:\desktop'
for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for subdir in dirs:
        dayFolder = os.path.join(rootdir, subdir)
        match = re.search('2022.January$',dayFolder)
        if match:
            os.close(os.path.join(dayFolder,day))
```

after i run it  i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\desktop\y\general\test1.py", line 21, in <module>
    os.close(os.path.join(dayFolder,day)) # close folder path
TypeError: an integer is required
>>>
```

update:
"close the sub directories" - i mean like clicking on the close button [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "close a folder"? (I'm somewhat afraid you will say "close the Explorer window that shows the folder contents" - I hope you mean something else)

Comment: OK so it is what I was afraid of. You can't do that with Python. (Unless of course you want to go into Win32 API programming, enumerate open windows, find the ones that are Explorer windows showing the folders you want, and sending window messages to them. It is *a lot* more complicated than trying `os.close()` and hoping it magically does what you mean.)

Comment: Maybe try AutoHotkey. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm